# mysql udf read my.cnf

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a `MySQL UDF (User Definied Function)`, which should read the configuration file of `MySQL - my.cnf` -, or access MySQL session and status vars.

How do I do that ?

I'm sure, there are functions implemented in MySQL source code - somewhere ...  for this functionality.

How do I find them?

Also, is there a good MySQL source API documentation?

Thanks,
krisy

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I found, was starting MySQL from a script, which script contains commands, to set enviromental variables, and accesss these variables througg `getenv()` function from UDF.

If anyone has a better solution, I'm interested very much :-)